# Trying to write to an existing file

Tags: vb.net

Hey guys I'm trying to write to an existing file. here is my code:

```
Dim writeFile1 As StreamWriter = File.OpenWrite("H:\Visual Basic\LoginFixed\Accounts\" + frmLogin.txtUser.Text)
```

It's saying that Error "Value of type 'System.IO.FileStream' cannot be converted to 'System.IO.StreamWriter'. "

Comment: I do not think it is a question.

Comment: You are trying to hammer a square peg into a round hole.  Use File.CreateText() instead.

Answer (score 1):

The exception indicates that the File.OpenWrite() method returns a FileStream object.

```
Dim writeFile1 As FileStream = File.OpenWrite("H:\Visual
Basic\LoginFixed\Accounts\" + frmLogin.txtUser.Text)
```

See the MSDN on [File.OpenWrite()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) for more information.

Comment: Then how would I write to the file? Before I was using writeFile1.WriteLine(frmClass.selection)

Comment: You would create a new instance of `StreamWriter` and pass it the `FileStream` as a parameter, like this: `Dim writeFile1 as StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("H:\Visual Basic\LoginFixed\Accounts\" + frmLogin.txtUser.Text))`

Comment: Thanks adrian, now how do I get rid of the login form and open a new one? Right now I'm doing             Dim newF As New frmClass
            Me.Hide()
            newF.Show() but it says it cannot be completed because the file is being used in another process, which that would be the 'me' @Adrian

Comment: @Programming16 that's a new question, you should accept this one and ask a new one.